# Remove first null value row based on row value of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have a table ABC

```
ClassId ClassName AccountId  AccountName
1         A        Null       Null
1         A        123        LNA
1         A        456        GFD
2         B        345        UYS
3         C         NULL      NULL
3         C         123        YTR
3         C         567        ERT
4         D         null       null
```

Output should be:

```
ClassId ClassName AccountId  AccountName
1         A        123        LNA
1         A        456        GFD
2         B        345        UYS
3         C         123        YTR
3         C         567        ERT
4         D         null       null
```

Need to remove first null value if other data present for the same classid and class name column.

Comment: "...if other data present for the same classid and class name..." -- can you show one case where this condition applies?

Comment: See line 1,2 and 3 , we are using class id 1 and class name A

Comment: And the opposite case?

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ABC t1
WHERE t1.AccountId IS NOT NULL AND t1.AccountName IS NOT NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM ABC t2
            WHERE t2.ClassId = t1.ClassId AND t2.ClassName = t1.ClassName
              AND t2.AccountId IS NOT NULL AND t2.AccountName IS NOT NULL
          );
```

or, if `AccountName` is `null` only when `AccountId` is `null` and `ClassName` is the same for each `ClassId`, you can use this simpler version:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM ABC t1
WHERE t1.AccountId IS NOT NULL
   OR NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM ABC t2
            WHERE t2.ClassId = t1.ClassId
              AND t2.AccountId IS NOT NULL
          );
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5fe96d8848dc147f8f338f0a67610a5e).